# I wish to express my thanks for this wonderful site, how and where can I do that?

Tags: support

This site, math stackexchange, is truly wonderful, with seeming hordes of mods helping and keeping the conversation civil and professional. I would like to express my thanks and tell them to keep up the good work. Is there an email or way to send my thanks, preferably to a head honcho?

Comment: no reason to downvote or remove such a  nice post even when it is a duplicate, maybe add a thanks tag to the meta site and if you don't like them ignore the tag.,

Comment: @Willemien You are missing some context here. The post is obviously sarcastic.

Comment: It most absolutely is not! I was utterly serious-- what in the world? That is quite offensive.

Comment: ...Someone is going to take that comment as sarcastic also. I was dead serious.